# In Firebase npm package, what is the meaning of "server (Node.js) clients"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm

AFAIK, in client-server computing, a server listens to requests and responds to them, and a client issues requests and gets replies from the server.

So, I am quite confused about the overloaded use of the words **server** and **client** in the **Overview** section at the beginning of the documentation of the **firebase** npm [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase).

It says:

> This package supports web (browser), mobile-web, and server (Node.js) clients.

I can decompose this into: "This package supports:

- web clients, a.k.a. browser clients
- mobile-web clients
- server clients, a.k.a. Node.js clients"

So, what does a "server client" mean, and what is a "Node.js client" ?

Comment: Means it can be used in the browser and node contexts. Not sure what else you are looking to define.

Comment: Firebase package has a lot of features, some of then can be used for web clients, mobile clients and others can be user as back end features, for example send a push notification, or creating a function, some of the things you can´t do while in a mobile-client or web client

Comment: @Phix I am not trying to define anything. I am trying to understand what is meant by "server (Node.js) clients". I understand that, before Node.js, the only way to run Javascript was inside a web browser. With Node.js, we can run Javascript from the command-line without a web-browser. I can write a Node.js application that runs on a server and serves HTML, CSS, and JS to be rendered by the browser. But, I can also run Node.js as a CLI on the client.